# Browser not redirecting to URL

Tags: javascript, html, angular, http, xmlhttprequest

I have an API that returns 302 status code with the destination location.
But when i am calling this API from my angular code, the browser is not redirecting to destination URL. Rather it's calling that destination URL(which is an HTML page) with XHR and giving error like:

**error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at Object.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad
text: "\n**

Basically it tried parse the HTML response as JSON and failed.
So how can I make browser to redirect to destination URL rather than calling it as XHR.

Comment: Can you share some code? And an object of what the response from the server looks like

Comment: Is the 302 for the next API call of for the client app?

Comment: API that returns 302 is returning URL of html page which the browser should open. But rather it's calling that URL as XHR and trying to parse it as JSON object..

Comment: The error suggests you are returning a non-JSON response from the API. Any HTTP API requests by default return responses as JSON format. Check your API HTTP call is not overriding the response type to a type that cannot be parsed as JSON.

Comment: The API is not returning any response, it just returns status code as 302 and in location it gives the destination URL which is an html page URL. After getting 302 it is calling that html page URL as XHR and trying to parse the HTML content as JSON hence failing.

Answer (score 0):

Browser won't jump to the `Location` which is returned by XHR 302 response's header. If you want to let the browser redirect, you should make it by your own.

Here is the code:

```
const url = 'http://your-api.com'
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        // This means our request undergoes a redirection
        if (xhr.responseURL !== url) {
            window.location = xhr.responseURL
        }
        else {
            // Do something else, like JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
        }
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', url)
xhr.send()
```